# How to add line numbers to a text file in functional programming (F#)?

Tags: f#, seq, readlines

It works with a for loop and mutable variable:

```
let addLnNum filename =    
    use outFile = new StreamWriter(@"out.txt")    
    let mutable count = 1
    for line in File.ReadLines(filename) do
        let newLine = addPre (count.ToString()) line
        outFile.WriteLine newLine
        count <- count + 1
```

But it is very "non-functional" so I'm curious what is the proper way to do this?
I figured how to append the index number to a list of strings:

```
let rec addIndex (startInd:int) l=
    match l with
    |x::xs ->  startInd.ToString()+x :: (addIndex (startInd+1) xs)
    |[] -> []
```

But it won't apply to File.ReadLines:

```
let addLnNum2 filename =    
    use outFile = new StreamWriter(@"out.txt")    
    File.ReadLines(filename)
    |> addIndex 1
    |> ignore
    //Error 1   Type mismatch. Expecting a Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> -> 'a    
    //but given a string list -> string list
```

Is reading the whole file into memory as a list the only way to do this? Is there something like seq.count so it can be done similar to the following?

```
let addLnNum3 filename =    
    use outFile = new StreamWriter(@"out.txt")    
    File.ReadLines(filename)
    |> Seq.map (fun s -> Seq.count + s) //no such thing as Seq.count
    |> Seq.iter outFile.WriteLine 
    |> ignore
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For some functions in the `Seq` module (same with `List`, ...) you'll find versions with an appended `i` - for example for `Seq.map` you'll find  `Seq.mapi` and this is what you are looking for - in addition to the value from your collection you get (as the first parameter) the index too:

```
let addLnNums filename =    
    use outFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter (@"out.txt")
    System.IO.File.ReadLines filename
    |> Seq.mapi (sprintf "%d: %s")
    |> Seq.iter outFile.WriteLine
```

also note that you don't need `ignore` as `Seq.iter` already returns `() : unit`

If we would not have this then the functional way would be to use `Zip` like this:

```
let addLnNum filename =    
    use outFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter (@"out.txt")
    Seq.zip (Seq.initInfinite id) (System.IO.File.ReadLines filename)
    |> Seq.map (fun (index, line) -> sprintf "%d: %s" index line)
    |> Seq.iter outFile.WriteLine
```

which (aside from uncurrying the function to `map`) does basically the same

---

#### Note:

For lists you obviously don't have a `List.initInfinte`, so just go with `Seq` - also `Seq.zip` and `List.zip` have different behaviors concerning collections with different item-count - `Seq.zip` stops when one collection runs try but `List.zip` wants both lists to be of the same size and will throw an exception if not

Comment: Thanks!! Much appreciated the solution with Zip method since I'm trying to learn how to do things in functional style

Answer (score 2):

Your `addIndex` function is actually correct - but it works on F# lists. The `ReadLine` function returns `IEnumerable<T>` rather than an F# list (which makes sense, because it is a .NET library). You can fix the `addLnNum2` function by adding `List.ofSeq` (to convert `IEnumerable<T>` to a list):

```
let addLnNum2 filename =    
    let added = 
      File.ReadLines(filename)
      |> List.ofSeq
      |> addIndex 1
    File.WriteAllLines("out.txt", added)
```

Using `Seq.mapi` or `Seq.zip` as mentioned in Carsten's answer is certainly simpler than implementing your own recursive function, but you did get the recursion and pattern matching right :-).

Comment: Please note that `List.ofSeq` will create a complete lists of all the content in memory (just commenting because it was mentioned in the question)